# Best Practice for wrapping non-class code

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, phpbb3

What is a good pattern for including and/or wrapping non-classes inside of a class? For example, I need to use this php file https://github.com/widop/phpbb3/blob/master/common.php to login to my phpbb board.  Specifically, I need this file to bootload phpbb and then I will use the $user and $auth variables to login a user.  In my code I have an AuthClient class.

I'm trying to figure out best practice to include common.php from phpbb and use it inside my class:

=========Edited Based On Feedback======================

I believe I've made an improvement, but it is still not working.
Getting an error:

```
[2013-09-05 14:28:49] log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Cannot redeclare class auth' in /var/www/phpbb3/includes/auth.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

This references the non-namespaced class loaded by bootstrap.php

```
https://github.com/widop/phpbb3/blob/master/common.php
https://github.com/widop/phpbb3/blob/master/includes/auth.php
```

## bootstrap.php

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = base_path() . "/phpbb3/";
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
require_once(base_path() . '/phpbb3/common.php');
```

## LoginController.php - Laravel

```
use myproject\models\User;
use myproject\models\phpbb\Phpbb;
use myproject\models\phpbb\AuthClient;
use myproject\models\phpbb\User as PhpbbUser;

require_once(base_path() . '/app/models/Phpbb/bootstrap.php');

class LoginController extends BaseController{
public function login(){
    //...login in main application
    //Login in phpbb - more ewww
    global $user;
    global $auth;
    $phpbb = new AuthClient($user, $auth);
    $phpbb->login();
}
}
```

## AuthClient.php

```
<?php
namespace myproject\models\phpbb;

use myproject\models\phpbb\Phpbb;

class AuthClient{

protected $user;
protected $auth;

public function  __construct($user, $auth){
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

public function login($user_id, $admin, $autologin){
    $this->user->session_begin();
    $this->auth->acl($this->user->data);
    $result = $this->user->session_create($user_id, $admin, $autologin, true);
}

public function logout(){
    $this->user->session_kill();
    $this->user->session_begin();
}
}
```

## original code prior to feedback - no longer using**

```
class AuthClient implements IAuthClient{

protected $user;
protected $auth;

public function  __construct(){
    /** Bootloading PHPBB */
    define('IN_PHPBB', true);
    $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
    $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

    // Start session management
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->user->session_begin();
    $this->auth->acl($user->data);

}

public function login($user_id, $admin, $autologin){
    $result = $this->user->session_create($user_id, $admin, $autologin, true);
}

public function logout(){
    $this->user->session_kill();
        $this->user->session_begin();
}
}
```

Comment: `define` in OO is declaring constant inside the class with `const MY_CONST = ...`

Comment: PHP is not Java, you don't have/should put everything inside a class if it doesn't make sense. And by the comments, you want your code compatible with PHP4. As you should already know, OO on PHP5 is very different from PHP4.

Comment: I've working on code that will not only log a user into my main site but also log them into subsystems (phpbb in this case).  In order to do this I've created an IAuthClient class.  Subsystems will implement this class, when the login is executed it will loop through all registered AuthClients and login.  So for my case, it makes sense to try to represent this phpbb login logic as a class.  Even if it is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Placing your code into constructor means the following:

- Anytime you create `new AuthClient() ;`, you will be executing the same code, defining already defined constants etc, which is a really bad idea and trigger an error.
- Also, methods can be static and thus, not creating an intance of the object, will not execute the code.

It is generally better to move the code not related to class outside, because sometimes you will not need anything, but just the class functionality. It is also better because the **file with class does not need to be included several times**, which will prevent repetitive execution of the code.

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

class AuthClient implements IAuthClient{

protected $user;
protected $auth;

}
```

Comment: so $user and $auth both come from the included common.php file.  How can I get them into the scope of the class with this approach?
In my code I will call new AuthClient();  At which point I guess through autoloading the phpbb bootloading would occur?

Comment: Just make a suitable constructor for that: `__construct($user, $auth){}` and create instances via `new AuthClient($user, $auth);`

Answer (score 0):

Including files in a class is bad practice as it couples the class to the file you're including and thus makes it impossible to reuse. An approach would be to store the class in a separate file and have the constructor like this (authclient.class.php):

```
class AuthClient implements IAuthClient {

    protected $user;
    protected $auth;

    public function  __construct(user $user, auth $auth){

    $this->user = $user;
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->user->session_begin();
    $this->auth->acl($user->data);

}
```

Then have another file which includes the phpbb file and your class and then instantiates your class.

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include('authclient.class.php');

$authClient = new AuthClient($user, $auth);
// do further processing with your authclient here
```

This way you have a good separation of the single concerns (phpbb, class declaration, business logic). If you end up having more custom classes you can use an autoloader to automate the inclusion of your classes.

Comment: I think this is getting me pretty close, but I'm still having one issue I described above.  I think its an issue of lack of namespacing in the included common.php.  Not sure how to overcome that.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace with the exception somewhere

Comment: You have this line twice
`use myproject\models\phpbbb\Phpbb;`
Removing it from the class file will probably work

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? Your file is so CORE procedural, you cannot just copy things and pass them in methods, the magic won't happen.

It doesn't come from common.php itself, it comes from the whole application.

If you have:

fila: a.php:

```
$a = 100;
function double($a) {
return $a*2;
}
```

file b.php

```
include "a.php";
$b = double($a);
echo $b; // 200
```

and you want b.php to become a class (?!), the bad approach to do this is:

```
Class B {
    private $_b;

    public function __construct() {
        include "a.php";
        $this->_b = double($a);
    }

    public function double() {
        return $this->_b;
    }
}
```

You have to refactor the included files to be compatible with the object manner:

```
Class A {
    public function double($a) {
        return $a*2;
    }
}
Class B {
    private $_a;
    private $_b;
    private $_inst;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_a = 100;
        $this->_inst = new A();
    }

    public function double($a) {
        $this->_b = $this->_inst->double($this->_a);
        return $this->_b;
    }
}
```

In your code, you have a lot of functions which are just function, ain't no methods or class instances. You are trying to access them by including them in the constructor, but it won't happen.

The instances of User, Auth, Template etc, should be injected in the constructor, or in separate method which uses dependency. In your code, $user and $auth are stateless, they do not become instances of the relevant classes.

If you want to refactor a code to become a Class, you have to stick to the object oriented manner. If you don't do it, then don't inject your code inside a class, it won't make it easier to reuse.